# Underscore.js why is this undefined

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am learning Underscore.js, see this code snippet

```
  var obj = function() {
    var foo = 1;
  }
  _(obj).extend({
    a: function(){
      var foo = 2;
      console.log("this.foo=" + this.foo + "\nthis=" + this + "\nfoo=" + foo + "\n\n");
    }
  });
  console.log("obj.a="+obj.a()+"\nobj="+obj);
```

The console output is

```
this.foo=undefined
this=function () {
    var foo = 1;
  }
foo=2

obj.a()=undefined
obj=function () {
    var foo = 1;
  }
```

Why are `this.foo` and `obj.a()` and  undefined?

Comment: `obj` is not a `{foo:1}`-object, but a function - which has properties like `.prototype`, `.name` or `.length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.foo` is undefined because `var foo` defines a variable in local scope, not a property of the object.

`obj.a()` is undefined because you do not return anything in the declared function.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `this.foo` and `foo` to line up you might want to use something like this:

```
  var foo = 2;

  var Obj = function() {
      var foo = 1;
  }

  var obj = _.extend(new Obj(), {
    foo : foo, 
    a: function(){
       console.log("this.foo=" + this.foo + "\nthis=" + this + "\nfoo=" + foo + "\n\n");
       return this.foo;
    }
  });
  console.log("obj.a="+obj.a()+"\nobj="+obj);
```

This gives output:

```
this.foo=2
this=[object Object]
foo=2

obj.a=2
obj=[object Object]
```

There were a few issues with the original code:

1. `_.extend` is the way to call the function you desired, `_` is the namespace and `extend` is the method name.
2. The output of `_.extend` is a copy, not an in-place replacement, so you should save the output as `obj` or some other variable name.
3. `foo` and `this.foo` are different.  `this.foo` is an attribute of the object (nameless object) which has the method `a` while `var foo` is a local variable inside of the `a` method.
4. If the above are fixed (for some version of the word fixed) then `obj.a()` has an undefined output because there is no return value.
5. `obj` the way you defined it was a function, but also essentially a class definition.

Adjustments: 
 1. I converted `obj` to `Obj` to signify it's status as a class.
 2. I added `var foo` to the same namespace that has `Obj`. 
 3. In the call to `_.extend` I instantiate an `Obj`.
 4. I synced `var foo` (temporarily) with `this.foo` by making it an attribute of the nameless object which you are extending with an `Obj` instance.
 5. Saved the output of `_.extend` as `obj`.
 6. I gave the method `a` a return value (I chose `this.foo`).

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyNovo/p8kVf/), note that the output is to the console.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `var Obj` vs later on just `obj` and not `var obj`. I understand using `var` or not has scoping implications but wondering if you had a reason.

Comment: I am also curious about this in Backbone.js without assigning it to var like you indicated `_.extend(View.prototype, Events, {...`

Comment: @cmnt1: oversight on my part, too many edits, thanks and fixed,
@cmnt2: `extend` and `Events` are mixed-in to the primary Backbone classes (Models, Views, Collections, Routers).  So `var MyViewClass = Backbone.View.extend({ alertBananas : function(){ alert(this.model.get('bananaCount') + ' bananas!');} });` creates a new view class inherited from the base View.  Now `var viewInstance = new MyViewClass({ model : new Backbone.Model({bananaCount : 7 }) });` means that `viewInstance` has all of the power of `Backbone.Events`, namely `listenTo` and `trigger`;

Comment: To clarify the Backbone side of things I created a fiddle for you which illustrates a basic set up: [http://jsfiddle.net/AndyNovo/G4LLn/](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyNovo/G4LLn/)